# JSON arrays into CLOB - Oracle

Tags: json, oracle, rest, plsql, oracle-fusion-apps

I have to build a following child json payload to supplment the main payload.  My question is how can I put these arrays into a clob to pass through as a PSLQL parameter.

Code:

```
Declare

l_children json_array_t;
p_clob CLOB

cursor getrec is select * from sometable;

begin

for i in getrec loop

    select TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'mmddyyyyhhmiss') into l_doc_id from dual;
 l_children.append(json_object_t('
            {
             
             "AttachedDocumentId": "'||l_doc_id||'",
             "DatatypeCode": "TEXT",
             "CategoryName": "INSTANCE_NUMBER",
             "UploadedText": "'||i.instance_number||'",
             "UploadedFileContentType": "text",
             "ContentRepositoryFileShared": "false",
             "Title": "'||i.instance_number||'",
             "Description": "'||i.instance_number||'"
             }'));
             
        select TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'mmddyyyyhhmiss') into l_doc_id from dual;
        
        l_children.append(json_object_t('
            {
             
             "AttachedDocumentId": "'||l_doc_id||'",
             "DatatypeCode": "TEXT",
             "CategoryName": "SERIAL_NUMBER",
             "UploadedText": "'||i.attachment_serial_number||'",
             "UploadedFileContentType": "text",
             "ContentRepositoryFileShared": "false",
             "Title": "'||i.attachment_serial_number||'",
             "Description": "'||i.attachment_serial_number||'"
             }'));
       
     end loop;
     p_Clob := l_children.to_clob;  /* this won't work */
```

Thank you
Darsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need cursors or loops; instead just use Oracle JSON functions:

```sql
Declare
  p_clob CLOB;
begin
  SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'AttachedDocumentId'          VALUE TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'mmddyyyyhhmiss'),
             KEY 'DatatypeCode'                VALUE 'TEXT',
             KEY 'CategoryName'                VALUE 'INSTANCE_NUMBER',
             KEY 'UploadedText'                VALUE instance_number,
             KEY 'UploadedFileContentType'     VALUE 'text',
             KEY 'ContentRepositoryFileShared' VALUE 'false' FORMAT JSON,
             KEY 'Title'                       VALUE instance_number,
             KEY 'Description'                 VALUE instance_number
           )
           RETURNING CLOB
         )
  INTO   p_clob
  FROM   sometable;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_clob);
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sometable(instance_number) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

Outputs:

> ```json
> [{"AttachedDocumentId":"09042023125446","DatatypeCode":"TEXT","CategoryName":"INSTANCE_NUMBER","UploadedText":1,"UploadedFileContentType":"text","ContentRepositoryFileShared":false,"Title":1,"Description":1},{"AttachedDocumentId":"09042023125446","DatatypeCode":"TEXT","CategoryName":"INSTANCE_NUMBER","UploadedText":2,"UploadedFileContentType":"text","ContentRepositoryFileShared":false,"Title":2,"Description":2},{"AttachedDocumentId":"09042023125446","DatatypeCode":"TEXT","CategoryName":"INSTANCE_NUMBER","UploadedText":3,"UploadedFileContentType":"text","ContentRepositoryFileShared":false,"Title":3,"Description":3}]
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y9_1ondL)

Comment: Thank you.  But I have a need to fetch some values in the payload from database cursor.

Comment: Also,  I would have to put each child payload (instance number and serial number) into different clob and than concatenate bot clobs into one clob and pass that into webservice, correct?

Comment: @virtualtransfer Use a `JOIN` if you want to fetch things from other tables. However, you do not show that in your question so we are not able to know that that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, your reply did help me figure it out.